# Intellij doesn't recognize package

Tags: java, intellij-idea, package

i got this sample solution from my Professor, but somehow it isn't working.
IntelliJ does not recognize the packages. That's the case for every class.
When I hover over it it says:
"Package name 'spaceman.view.util' does not correspond to the file path 'view.util' "
Has anyone any idea what could be wrong?
I'm a total beginner when it comes to coding so sorry, if the question is banal.

Thank you!!

[image: IntelliJ Screen]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your project `spaceman` is the sources root. That means anything inside a folder `view/welcome` in that folder is supposed to be in the package `view.welcome`. If you want to keep the package `spaceman.view.welcome` then move the whole tree into another folder `spaceman` inside your `spaceman` project directory.

Note that it's rather unusual to have the project root itself be the source root. It's way more common to have a directory like `src/` be the source root (or, if you  follow the Maven/Gradle convention something like `src/main/java`).